# Cannot pass the props value?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, prop

Im new to react, and now is going to pass the id from one page to another page by `props`. But I'm not sure is it the correct way to pass it.

Consider the code below:

```
<div  className="submit-button">
    <input type="submit" 
        value="Purchase" 
        className="btn btn-primary mt-2 text-capitalize " 
        onClick={this.handleClickPurchase}
    />
</div>
```

```
        handleClickPurchase(){
            window.location.href='/PurchaseInformation'
            return(
                <PurchaseInformation value={this.state.data.id}/>
            )
        }
```

On my Purchase Information page

```
render(props){
    console.log(this.props.value)
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div>
          <h1> {this.props.value}</h1>
          <h2> Purchase Information Page is under development </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: returning <PurchaseInformation /> from handleClickPurchase doesn't do anything. When you go to new url, you should use [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to render new component. And to share information between pages, you can use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or third party library, like redux and mobx

Answer (score 0):

As @Ido mentioned **`return <PurchaseInformation value={this.state.data.id}/>`** doesn't do anything.

Are you rendering `PurchaseInformation` in your parent component?
If so just use `<PurchaseInformation value={this.state.data.id}/>` in your render function.

I would use destructing syntax, makes it easier to use props/object.

```
render(){
   const {value} = this.props;
    console.log(value)
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div>
          <h1>{value}</h1>
          <h2>Purchase Information Page is under development</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```